# Find a value in a array given multiple conditions

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Here is what I'm trying to achive:
If I run this line

```
(df[:,0] < df[2,16]).argmax()
```

it will return me the first value in column 0 that is lower than df[16,2] (yellow and red lines)

The thing is, I need the code to return me the NEXT time a value will be lower than df[16,2] in this case, df[0,17].

How can I add this argument (selecting next based on index position) to this code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following code should give you the complete list of indices where the condition `df.iloc[:,0] < df.iloc[16,2]` is `True`.

```
  match_idx = df.index[(df.iloc[:,0] < df.iloc[16,2])==True].tolist()
```

Should you require the second matching index, you can get it using  `match_idx[1]`

```
second_match = match_idx[1]
```